# uvm_field_* macros - how do I set my custom struct

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I can't find a uvm_field_* macro that I can use in my testbench. I defined a struct:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned byte red;
   unsigned byte green;
   unsigned byte blue;
} pixel;
```

Now, in my sequence item, I declare:

```
rand pixel unsigned data[];
rand int   unsigned height;
rand int   unsigned width;

`uvm_object_utils_begin(cgs_rgb_trans_t)
  `uvm_field_int(height, UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_field_int(width, UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_field_array_pixel(data, UVM_ALL_ON)
`uvm_object_utils_end
```

I doubt this will work. Can i just register it as `uvm_field_array_int? What is the method to do this?

Comment: Make your own field macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my organization, we do not recommend using the field automation macros because of these limitations, confusion over which cases are auto-configured, and the severe performance penalty they impose.  In addition, so-called UVM **ints** are internally represented as 4K bit vectors, wasting lots of memory. See [this article](https://dvcon-proceedings.org/document/are-ovm-uvm-macros-evil-a-cost-benefit-analysis/) for more info and alternatives.

Comment: so i guess its not possible! i would think uvm_field_* macros are templated to accept any type. oh well..

Answer (score 1):

You always could use `'uvm_field_array_int` and a pair of pack/unpack function that transforms the pixel info into an int (you would still have a byte of the int free) and the other way round. Your sequence would have, instead of an array of pixels, an array of ints, and then you could transform from/to in the driver and monitor.

Comment: Not having a pack/unpack function is the reason I wanted to go with a typdef pixel in the first place. I wanted to be able to refer to each component of the pixel as data[i].red, data[i].green etc. rather than byte red = (data[i]>>16) & 'hFF